# Calculate the centre $Z(G)=\{g\in G| gx=xg \forall x\in G\}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

Let $G$ be the symmetry group of a square. The first exercise is that I describe $G$ as a permutation group. I've found the following permutations:

$
\begin{align*}
\tau_1 &= \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2& 3& 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4
\end{pmatrix},\tau_2 = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2& 3& 4 \\ 2 & 3 & 4 & 1
\end{pmatrix}, \tau_3 = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2& 3& 4 \\ 3 & 4 & 1 & 2
\end{pmatrix},\tau_4 = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2& 3& 4 \\ 4 & 1 & 2 & 3
\end{pmatrix}\\
\tau_5 &= \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2& 3& 4 \\ 4 & 3 & 2 & 1
\end{pmatrix},
\tau_6= \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2& 3& 4 \\ 3 & 2& 1 & 4
\end{pmatrix},
\tau_7= \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2& 3& 4 \\ 2 & 1 & 4 & 3
\end{pmatrix},
\tau_8= \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2& 3& 4 \\ 1 & 4 & 3 & 2
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
$

I don't know how I can describe $G$ as a permutation group and the last exercise is that I calculate the center of $G$

$$Z(G):=\{g\in G| gx=xg\ \forall x\in G\}.$$

I know what a center is. But how can I calculate it if I have a matrix?

Comment: I don't understand, didn't you describe $G$ as a permutation group above by giving the explicit permutations each element correspond to ?

Comment: $\tau_1, \ldots, \tau_4$ are rotations of the square (including the trivial one), and $\tau_5, \ldots, \tau_8$ are reflections. The rotations commute with one another. None of the reflections commute with one another (verify). Which rotations commute with all reflections? The identity/trivial one, definitely. Any other? [Yes, one more].

Comment: @M.Vinay There are (distinct) reflections that do commute! But they do not commute with *all* reflections

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Oh yes, any two reflections whose product is the central element do commute with each other, of course. I should've said the none of the reflections commute with all the other reflections.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

This group has two generators: a reflection $s$ (there are $4$ of them) and  rotation $r$ of $\pi/2$ around the centre of the square, together with the relations:
$$s^2=1,\quad r^4=1,\quad sr=r^3s.$$
An element commutes with every element in the group if and only if it commutes with $r$ and $s$.

Answer (score 1):

As Bernard points out, we have $x \in Z(D_4)$ if and only if:

$rxr^{-1} = x\\sxs^{-1} = x.$

The key to computing these conjugates is the rule: $sr^ks^{-1} = r^{-k}$.

---

(To show your permutations in "matrix form" ARE (isomorphic to) $D_4$, you need only verify the relations: $(\tau_2)^4 = (\tau_5)^2 = \tau_1$ and:

$\tau_5\tau_2\tau_5 = \tau_4$ -this last one is easiest to do in "cycle form", since we have for a cycle:

$\alpha = (a_1\ a_2\ \cdots\ a_k)$, and any permutation $\sigma$, that:

$\sigma\alpha\sigma^{-1} = (\sigma(a_1)\ \sigma(a_2)\ \cdots \ \sigma(a_k))$

In your case, we have:

$\alpha = \tau_2 = (1\ 2\ 3\ 4)$, and $\sigma = \tau_5 = (1\ 4)(2\ 3)$, so that:

$\tau_5(1) = 4\\ \tau_5(2) = 3\\ \tau_5(3) = 2\\ \tau_5(4) = 1.$

So $\tau_5\tau_2\tau_5 = (4\ 3\ 2\ 1) = (1\ 4\ 3\ 2) = \tau_4$,

and then show that $\tau_2,\tau_5$ generate the whole group ($\tau_2$ clearly generates the first four elements, so you just have to write $\tau_6,\tau_7,\tau_8$ as "words" in $\tau_2$ and $\tau_5$-hint: multiply powers of $\tau_2$ by $\tau_5$ and "see what you get").

---

There are "two types" of elements, those of the form $r^k$ for $k = 0,1,2,3$ (these are rotations), and those of the form $r^ks$ (these are reflections).

For a rotation to be in the center (it always commutes with $r$, so we just check conjugation by $s$), we need:

$r^k = r^{-k}$, and you should be able to instantly see only two values of $k$ work.

So let's look at a reflection:

$r(r^ks)r^{-1} = r^{k+1}sr^3 = r^{k+1}(sr^3)ss  = r^{k+1}(sr^3s)s = r^{k+1}rs = r^{k+2}s$.

This alone shows no reflection is in the center.

You can easily generalize this to $D_n$ (the dihedral group of order $2n$, the symmetries of a regular $n$-gon) and you see such centers come in "two flavors" depending on whether or not $n$ is odd.